# Bottom Navigation View setSelectedItem crashing app in Android Java

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented this Bottom Navigation Code in my app and I seem to have an issue whenever I try to set the selected item id on the view. It crashes the app when I try to set the selected item id...Please help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Date mydate;
ImageButton myfloat;
TextView view,minfo1,minfo2,minfo3;
TextView[] medicalinfos;
Typeface Ubuntu;
BottomNavigationView navView;
ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
         //define Bottom NavigationView
        navView =findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //Set a onselecteditemlistener for this Bottom Navigation View
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        }
        //Define the listener
              @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id=item.getItemId();
            switch(id){
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
                    actionBar.setTitle("Medical Information");
                    break;
                case  R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    //navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_notifications);
                    actionBar.setTitle("Notifications");
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    //navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
                    actionBar.setTitle("History");
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_graphic:
                    actionBar.setTitle("More Information");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };    
}
```

Here is the logcat error

```
at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
2021-03-10 23:16:25.010 27238-27238/com.example.medicalnotifier E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:241)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
2021-03-10 23:16:25.011 27238-27238/com.example.medicalnotifier E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(BottomNavigationView.java:558)
        at com.example.medicalnotifier.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:58)
```

Whenever I try to uncomment the lines in the switch statement above and select on a Bottom Navigation menu item, the app crashes...Please help[image: Navigation Icons]

Comment: Can you post the exception or exact error? Also why don't you just do: navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

Comment: am gonna try that now, getting back to you in a moment

Comment: I updated my question with the logcat

Comment: Put the complete logcat please, not just the last part

Comment: It keeps repeating that same block all over the logcat window

Comment: I updated my question, please check

Comment: Since you keep navListener, post the code of that listener too

Comment: I did as you said and its still throwing the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229749/discussion-between-javdromero-and-codetiger).

Answer (score 1):

```
  case R.id.navigation_notifications:
       navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_notifications);
```

You shouldn't use `setSelectedItem` within `onNavigationItemSelected`, because the item is already selected, so why you repeat yourself again ... the `NavigationItemSelectedListener` callback itself is called because you already selected the item..

In the above snippet when you hit the `R.id.navigation_notifications` item the `onNavigationItemSelected` callback is triggered and you again use `setSelectedItemId` to select the same item again then the listener callback is called once more, and this would be repeated forever..

So, you need to remove these `setSelectedItemId` statements from within the `NavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: If you have some purpose to use `setSelectedItem` you can tell us so we can understand more.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what i was looking for, seems you can't use `setSelectedItem` because its kind of `circular(repeitive)`
using this works to set the Menu Item checked

```
  navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_dashboard).setChecked(true);
```